# Изменить свойство для всех объектов в массиве исключая один объект

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, foreach, map

У меня есть массив объектов areas:

```
areas:[
0: {
  "id_ou": 1,
  "lp": 1,
  "nazwa_ou": "Edukacja",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "EDU_ikona.PNG"
}
1:{
  "id_ou": 2,
  "lp": 2,
  "nazwa_ou": "Lokalna polityka społeczna",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "SPO_ikona.PNG"
}
2:{
  "id_ou": 3,
  "lp": 3,
  "nazwa_ou": "Kultura i rekreacja ",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "KUL_ikona.PNG"
}
3:{
  "id_ou": 4,
  "lp": 4,
  "nazwa_ou": "Drogownictwo i Transport",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "DT _ikona.PNG"
}
4:{
  "id_ou": 5,
  "lp": 5,
  "nazwa_ou": "Ochrona środowiska",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "OS _ikona.PNG"
}
5:{
  "id_ou": 6,
  "lp": 6,
  "nazwa_ou": "Gospodarowanie nieruchomościami",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "GN _ikona.PNG"
}
6:{
  "id_ou": 7,
  "lp": 7,
  "nazwa_ou": "Inwestycje i budownictwo",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": true,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "IB _ikona.PNG"
}
7:{
  "id_ou": 8,
  "lp": 8,
  "nazwa_ou": "Geodezja i kartografia",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "GK _ikona.PNG"
}
8:{
  "id_ou": 9,
  "lp": 9,
  "nazwa_ou": "Podatki i opłaty lokalne",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": true,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "POL_ikona.PNG"
}]
```

Я в React устанавливаю selectedTab ,  например "Geodezja i kartografia" как выбранный объект и меняю в нем свойство "czy_domyslny": true, и получаю новый массив с измененным свойством этого объекта:

```
areas:[
0: {
  "id_ou": 1,
  "lp": 1,
  "nazwa_ou": "Edukacja",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "EDU_ikona.PNG"
}
1:{
  "id_ou": 2,
  "lp": 2,
  "nazwa_ou": "Lokalna polityka społeczna",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "SPO_ikona.PNG"
}
2:{
  "id_ou": 3,
  "lp": 3,
  "nazwa_ou": "Kultura i rekreacja ",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "KUL_ikona.PNG"
}
3:{
  "id_ou": 4,
  "lp": 4,
  "nazwa_ou": "Drogownictwo i Transport",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "DT _ikona.PNG"
}
4:{
  "id_ou": 5,
  "lp": 5,
  "nazwa_ou": "Ochrona środowiska",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "OS _ikona.PNG"
}
5:{
  "id_ou": 6,
  "lp": 6,
  "nazwa_ou": "Gospodarowanie nieruchomościami",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "GN _ikona.PNG"
}
6:{
  "id_ou": 7,
  "lp": 7,
  "nazwa_ou": "Inwestycje i budownictwo",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": true,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "IB _ikona.PNG"
}
7:{
  "id_ou": 8,
  "lp": 8,
  "nazwa_ou": "Geodezja i kartografia",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": true,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "GK _ikona.PNG"
}
8:{
  "id_ou": 9,
  "lp": 9,
  "nazwa_ou": "Podatki i opłaty lokalne",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": true,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "POL_ikona.PNG"
}]
```

Теперь мне нужно перебрать полученный измененный  массив areas и изменить в нем все свойства `"czy_domyslny": true`, на `"czy_domyslny": false`, исключая выбранный в массиве `selectedTab`.

Как это лучше сделать? через `forEach` исключая `id_ou` выбранного мной обьекта `selectedTab`?

Comment: Может быть Вам нужен `Array.filter` ?

Comment: у меня стоит вопрос именно в том, как это кодом сделать, мозгами я понимаю что нужно фильтр  с forEach ( с id_ou != selectedTab.id_ou)  и в зависимости от этого условия во всем массиве изменить свойствовсем объектам которые удовлетворяют условию,только код мой не работает, я не совсем понимаю как приавильно делать фильтрацию с forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{
  "id_ou": 1,
  "lp": 1,
  "nazwa_ou": "Edukacja",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "EDU_ikona.PNG"
}, {
  "id_ou": 2,
  "lp": 2,
  "nazwa_ou": "Lokalna polityka społeczna",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "SPO_ikona.PNG"
}, {
  "id_ou": 3,
  "lp": 3,
  "nazwa_ou": "Kultura i rekreacja ",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "KUL_ikona.PNG"
}, {
  "id_ou": 4,
  "lp": 4,
  "nazwa_ou": "Drogownictwo i Transport",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "DT _ikona.PNG"
}, {
  "id_ou": 5,
  "lp": 5,
  "nazwa_ou": "Ochrona środowiska",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "OS _ikona.PNG"
}, {
  "id_ou": 6,
  "lp": 6,
  "nazwa_ou": "Gospodarowanie nieruchomościami",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "GN _ikona.PNG"
}, {
  "id_ou": 7,
  "lp": 7,
  "nazwa_ou": "Inwestycje i budownictwo",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": true,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "IB _ikona.PNG"
}, {
  "id_ou": 8,
  "lp": 8,
  "nazwa_ou": "Geodezja i kartografia",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": false,
  "czy_aktywny": false,
  "plik_png": "GK _ikona.PNG"
}, {
  "id_ou": 9,
  "lp": 9,
  "nazwa_ou": "Podatki i opłaty lokalne",
  "nazwa_ou_ang": "",
  "czy_domyslny": true,
  "czy_aktywny": true,
  "plik_png": "POL_ikona.PNG"
}]

let selectedTab = 'Geodezja i kartografia' //условно, это стейт реакта

//принимает исходный массив и то, что должно быть активным
let domyslnySwitch = (data, active) => {
  return data.map((item) => //используем Array.map для перебора массива
    (item.nazwa_ou == active) //если название элемента совпадает с тем, что должен быть активным
    ? item //ничего не делаем, возвращаем элемент массива.
    : { ...item, czy_domyslny: false } //в противном случае, с флагом false
  )
}

//Пример через forEach
let domyslnySwitchForEach = (data, active) => {
  let newData = []; //новый массив
  
  data.forEach((item)=>{
    if(item.nazwa_ou == active) //если имя совпадает
       newData.push(item) //то пушим в новый массив элемент без изменений 
    else //если нет
      newData.push({...item, czy_domyslny: false}) //изменяем св-во и пушим в новый массив
      //надеюсь, вы знакомы с деструктуризацией
  })
  
  return newData; //ф-я возвращает новый массив
}




let newArr = domyslnySwitch(arr, selectedTab); //вызываем ф-ю

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Вы меня немного не поняли :) логика выбора активного обьекта есть,суть моего вопроса, мне нужно изменить свойство во всех обьектах нового массива с исключением того,котрый выбраню именно функция перебора массива с исключением объекта по id_ou

Comment: 1. Что вы имеете ввиду под "с исключением"? Активный элемент должен быть исключен из нового массива? Или на нем просто не должно меняться св-во czy_domyslny? 2. map - это и есть перебор массива, или вам нужен строго forEach? Сейчас функция создает новый массив и выставляет для всех элементов, кроме активного, св-во czy_domyslny в false.

Comment: под исключением я понимаю,что в новом массиве, в который записался мой selectedTab уже с новым свойством ```czy_domyslny: true``` нужно всем остальным обьектам изменить это свойство на ```czy_domyslny: false```

Comment: Нужно что-то наподобие этой логики: берем массив и меняем в нем всем обьектам значение ```czy_domyslny : false ``` а обьекту который selectedTab мы это свойство не меняем. примечание: selectedTab это не более чем указание обьекта, то есть этот обьект сидит в массиве новом а не в переменной.

Comment: Или на нем просто не должно меняться св-во czy_domyslny? - совершенно верно

Comment: собственно все это и делает ф-я. Окей, внес конкретную правку, что, если имя указанного активного элемента совпадает с элементом массива в переборе, то map просто возвращает элемент без изменений, для всех остальных элементов выставляет св-во в false.

Comment: @MariiaKramarenko добавил вам пример с forEach

Comment: через пуш я делала так же как и Вы, но проблема в том ,что пуш добавляет измененный объект в конец массива ,а я не могу менять порядок обьектов в массиве

Comment: К тому же, мне нужно сделать логику изменения свойств в ```useEffect(()=>{
 
  }, [selectedTab]);
```

Comment: То есть пользовтель сделал action, записался selectedTab на то же место в массиве где и был просто с другим значением , уже ```czy_domyslny: true``` и мне нужно каждый раз когда пользователь выбирает другой selectedTab грубо говоря чистить массив и менять у всех остальных значений его строго на ```czy_domyslny: false``` я понимаю что это перебор массива с исключением по id_ou, не цепляйтесь именно к реакту,мне нужна просто функция :)

Comment: Что у вас с пушем не получалось, я не знаю, в примерах выше все работает на 100% по описанной вами логике.

Comment: пуш добавляет объект в конец массива а я не могу менять расположение объектов

Comment: Мария, еще раз. Мы в функции создаем новый ПУСТОЙ массив, в нем 0 элементов. Перебираем мы ИСХОДНЫЙ массив с первого по последний элемент ПО ОЧЕРЕДИ. Т.е. сначала мы пушим первый элемент (индекс 0, в новом массиве он будет также с индексом 0), потом второй (он также и останется с индексом 1) и т.д. до конца. Порядок элементов в новом массиве НЕ ИЗМЕНИТСЯ. Если вам это не понятно, то лучше отложите react и вернитесь к базе JS - Array.prototype.reduce, Array.prototype.map, Array.prototype.filter, Array.prototype.forEach, т.к. у вас в этом вопросе огромнейший пробел.

Comment: Спасибо огромное,прошу прощения , все верно,это я недосмотрела, чисто из-за невнимательности, Все работает!